# Failure to find javax.transaction:jta: in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I just created web application using maven -3.2.3 and there after i just some dependencies in pom.xml next just right click on my pom.xml-->RunAs-->maven install.All jars are downloaded.Then while trying to build(like my pom.xml-->RunAs-->maven build) i got one pop up to set goal. i just typed goal field as a "package" -->run.
 i am facing below issue

```
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6.jar (2881 KB at 3.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15:26.448s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 29 08:33:31 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpringMVCMaven: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.rajendra.spring:SpringMVCMaven:war:1.0: Failure to find javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

and for reference below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.rajendra.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>SpringMVCMaven Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCMaven</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Could you suggest me where exactly things are getting wrong. Appreciating your help here

Answer (score 5):

You're having a problem because you're using relatively old frameworks. They are dependent upon a version of JTA that could not be made available in a public repository due to licensing restrictions. In that era there were a number of artifacts like this that we had to download from Sun (after agreeing to the licence) and install in our own local repository.

Thankfully, in your case you just need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml and that should override the older version.

This is a newer version but it only contains API classes (not implementations) and I believe that it is backward compatible.